# Connecting to Docker API with curl

Tags: api, curl, docker

I'm using Kitematic on a mac and I'm trying to connect to the docker events API using curl.

```
curl --no-buffer -XGET --unix-socket tcp://192.168.99.102:2376 http://events
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

However, it won't connect to the server. This connects:

```
telnet 192.168.99.102 2376
Trying 192.168.99.102...
Connected to 192.168.99.102.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I also tried the Ruby Docker library that can successfully subscribe to the event stream.

Answer (score 2):

#### The problem is

.. the `curl` command tries to connect to a `--unix-socket`, while you give a TCP socket when in fact you need to connect to a web daemon.

#### Try this

`curl --no-buffer -XGET http://0.0.0.0:2376/events`

That worked for me.